# Due to allergies, I'm limited to avocado mayo, it taste like drywall, what can I do to make it palatable?

Tags: flavor

My favorite is Hellman's mayo, but I can't have it as I get severe inflammation from the canola oil that is part of its ingredients. This avocado mayo was the alternative I found locally but doesn't taste anything like mayo, that I find palatable, what can I add to fix that? When I tried it it tasted like drywall. Imagine some drywall dust going up your nose and you accidentally swallowed some, yeah. It doesn't have to taste like Hellman's just mayo flavor would suffice.

What can I add or do to it to taste a bit more like mayo?

[image]

Comment: Have you considered just making homemade mayonnaise, with whatever oil you like?

Comment: I've tasted drywall dust, it had a slight toxic mineral character. I feel your pain, alternatives don't always work out the way we want them to. Do all oils give you trouble or just some of them? Other than avocado what can you tolerate?

Comment: In Canada, Hellmans sells an olive oil mayo as well as a vegan one. If you need to avoid canola (rather than eggs) I don't think this avocado based one is your only option. Try some more. Try making mayo at home too -- olive oil, egg yolk, little seasoning, whiz with a stick blender. You have choices!

Comment: @Kate Gregory Hellman's Olive oil Mayo is part olive oil mixed with canola oil. First thing I did is go to my local IGA to walk back home empty handed.

Comment: @GdD All seed oils, all Rapeseed oil eg:canola, sunflower oil, causes to inflame, itch and bleeding. Peanut oil causes no problems, coconut oil, avocado oil are all good for me.

Comment: @Sneftel I'll have to learn how to but, ya know, can't do that on this site.

Comment: I think it's a really good advise to make your own. The process itself is extremely easy and fast. It really takes a couple of minutes only.  Of course with so many options of oils and flavours and recipes it will most likely take a while to discover what you really like, but you are in full control what you add to it so in context of allergies it's perfect, if you are willing to spend some time experimenting and trying things out.

Comment: @Martynas Žiemys "many salmonellosis cases still occur as a result of catering and home-made mayonnaise consumption." There's experimenting and then there taking risks.

Comment: Don't take risks then. You can pasteurise eggs with a microwave if you are worried.

Comment: @Martynas Žiemys I seen microwaved eggs, what a nasty explosion! I found a pasteurization method using a pot of water. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but I have seen it done in some videos online. You should not microwave the whole egg, there is some process with some seconds in, some stirring or something then repeating... You should research it if you are interested. I am not worried about salmonellosis myself, it's very rare where I live and it's not like it's deadly, its just not a huge concern for me personally. I accept the risks if I want to make something out of raw eggs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your description it's hard to know what flavor is missing, or it has too much of, so I'll give you the general approach I'd take.

Mayo is an emulsion of oil, eggs and vinegar. The emulsion of oil and eggs is by itself pretty bland, so producers add sugar, salt, and/or spices in various quantities, I'm going to guess that the difference in flavor is down how much of those flavorings are added. The answer is probably on the labels.

Your brand of avocado mayo has zero sugar, whereas Hellmans has 1.3g of sugar per 100g. Chosen's serving size is an annoying 14g but multiplying the amounts by 7 gives us a 100g equivalent, doing that with the salt shows us that your avocado mayo has .35g of salt per 100g, whereas Hellmans has 1.2g per 100g. In other words, the avocado mayo is bland with a capital B! It's also likely to be lacking acidity and spices as there's no sugar to balance it out.

You can make up for these deficiencies by adding small amounts of sugar and salt, plus maybe some white vinegar or lemon juice until you get a result you like. Paprika is in Hellman's recipe as well, so a dash of that would be good too. I'd experiment on smaller quantities to see what works, then once you get a flavor you like replicate that using similar but scaled up proportions.

Comment: I will try to add some sucralose, some salt, and some Realemon lemon concentrate. I suspect that avocado mayo is health orientated therefore devoid of anything else that might scare the health restricted.

Comment: Also some Paprika.